# Is Java a bad choice when I take part in programming contests?

Tags: java, memory, constraints

Most contests have a limit on  time and memory taken by the processor to compute the answer, and if the code is written in Java, which runs on a virtual machine, there would be an overhead and requires more time for the program to  compute compared to many other ones.  Many contests also base the ranking of contestants based on the time taken for the program to run.

So I like to know about the evaluation based on the choice of programming language used to submit the solutions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As with everything, it depends. Are you doing something that requires high performance? Is it scored by time/memory efficiency, or does it just require that you don't go over the limits?